# jQuery validation plugin not validating pre-filled select

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a very strange issue with the jQuery Validation plugin where it won't validate a `select` that was pre-filled then modified.

You can look at the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/VwRJ8/1/

The code never fires the `alert()` in the following lines:

```
$('#edit_loc_save').click(function() {
    var foo = $('#add_new_loc_form').valid();
    alert(foo);
});
```

Comment: The `select` box will validate on submit but not initially on change. Also you should put a `name` value for your `select`.

Comment: I should have been more specific. It's not validating on submit.

Comment: There might be an error in your javascript causing the validate function to never be called. Your example code works fine on submit. Here is a demo showing so: http://jsfiddle.net/bPcr8/5/. Check your error console to see if there are any errors. Otherwise, can you share a live version of the problem for everyone?

Comment: Here's a fiddle that's very close to the live code. Yo can reproduce the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/VwRJ8/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if the select is valid each time the value is changed:

**Javascript**

```
$('#myform').validate();
$('#myselectbox').on('change', function() {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bPcr8/3/)**

**Edit 1**

Here is what is causing an error in your javascript, which is preventing the validate function to operate correctly:

```
new_loc_zip: {
    required: true,
    postalcode: true // This is not a correct setting in jquery validate
},
```

If you remove the `postalcode: true` line, validate will call properly.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VwRJ8/5/)**

Comment: I have a custom validation rule for postalcode that I forgot to include :\ Would that still cause an issue?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VwRJ8/6/ there doesn't seem to be an issue with the validation rule in. Select is being validated correctly.

Comment: It is bizaare that I can't get it to work on the actual code (It's inside a corporate network so I can't show it). I do have multiple forms with separate validation rules. I wonder if that's the issue.

Comment: Bizarre. Good luck. My tip would be to view your error console as you submit the form and see if there are any errors. If you are able to recreate the problem in the fiddle we can try to help you. Otherwise, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/YRAga/2/

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        myselectbox: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});

$("#myselectbox").change(function() {
    $("#myform").submit();
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do the validation while changing the option, then try to handle the change event of the select option and trigger the validation programatically

Try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myselectbox').change(function() {
              $('#myform').validate({
                            rules: {
                              myselectbox: {required: true }
                            }
                          }).form();
                       });
                    });​
```

See the fiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5zbys/)

Comment: can not call validate() more than one time!